# Correct transition for pvc conduit to liquid tight flexible conduit on a concrete slab

Tags: concrete, conduit, slab

I am installing conduit for a hot tub.  I have conduit coming up from underground at the edge of the slab and I wondering how to transition it to liquid tight flexible conduit on top of the slab.  The poorly drawn image below illustrates what I was thinking of doing.  Is this ok or would it be better to bend the conduit or use a 90 degree over the corner and use a straight connector to join the pvc to the liquid tight conduit?  I am planning on using 2' x 2' deck tiles to cover up the slab and the conduit after everything is installed. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your plan will work but depending on the distances in each direction, pulling the large wires that a hot tub requires could be tough. Think about using a PVC LB similar to the one pictured below. It's neat and clean and you can pull wires much easier with the LB access. You would have to stub a small  piece of PVC to the LB and use a female adapter to accept the liquid tight straight connector(Thanks to @ThreePhaseEel).

[image]

Comment: Note that gluing LFNC (carflex) into a LB isn't really what you're supposed to do here -- I'd use a short "stub" section of PVC and a female adapter to accept the LFNC connector as UL 651 1.5.2 states that internal PVC device threads are meant to join to either RMC *or* other externally-threaded devices

Comment: It's one of those things that's common practice despite not being within the scope of the product listings/standards in question -- UL 514C states in 5.3.2 that PVC boxes and LBs are intended to be joined to rigid nonmetallic (PVC) conduit, not any type of flexible conduit

Comment: Very interesting. I've seen LFNC glued into LB's at countless marinas and sea walls.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an LB, LR, or LL, my understanding is that code requires you to maintain access to the removable plate; I’d use a sweep 90 degree bend instead. This way, you can, if needed, pull the wire out later to pull others in.